# Why do I get '\u{0}' when printing artist info from an mp3 file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm working on a project where I collect metadata of an mp3 file and I should put it in a `MusicFile` struct. I have a problem when a try to print my `Vec<MusicFile>`, I have in the output:

```
 artiste: "DORETDEPLATINE\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}\u{0}",
```

DORETTDEPLATINE is my mp3 title I don't know why the `\u{0}` appears.
The code in my scan function is:

```
pub fn scan(path: &Path) -> Vec<MusicFile> {
    let mut music_files: Vec<MusicFile> = Vec::new();
    let walker = WalkDir::new(path).into_iter();
    for entry in walker {
        let entry = match entry {
            Ok(entry) => entry,
            Err(_) => panic!("Probleme"),
        };

        if is_supported(&entry) {
            let meta_music = mp3_metadata::read_from_file(entry.path()).expect("file err"); //convert an entry to path like 9
            let meta_file = fs::metadata(entry.path()).expect("error");
            //println!("la taille est {}",meta_file.len());
            //println!("la date creat est {:?}",meta_file.created());//Date creation file
            let mut artiste = String::new();
            let mut year: u16 = Default::default();
            let mut title = String::new();
            let mut album = String::new();
            if let Some(tag) = meta_music.tag {
                artiste = tag.artist;
                year = tag.year;
                title = tag.title;
                album = tag.album;
            }
            //println!("L'ALBUM EST {}",album);
            music_files.push(MusicFile::new(
                entry.path(),
                artiste,
                meta_file.len(),
                year,
                album,
                title,
                meta_file.created(),
            ));
        }
    }
    music_files
}
```

and my `MusicFile` is:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::time::SystemTime;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MusicFile {
    path: PathBuf,
    artiste: String,
    taille: u64,
    annee: u16,
    album: String,
    titre: String,
    date_crea: Result<SystemTime, std::io::Error>,
}

impl MusicFile {
    pub fn new(path: &Path, artiste: String, taille: u64, annee: u16, album: String, titre: String, date_crea: Result<SystemTime, std::io::Error>) -> MusicFile {
        MusicFile {
            path: path.to_path_buf(),
            artiste: artiste,
            taille: taille,
            annee: annee,
            album: album,
            titre: titre,
            date_crea: date_crea,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_titre(&self) -> String {
        self.titre.clone()
    }
}
```

and finally my `main()` just prints the `Vec<MusicFile>` returned from `scan()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v1_and_ID3v1.1%5B5%5D) metadata tag uses a fixed-width field for the `"artist"` info. It appears the [mp3_metadata](https://crates.io/crates/mp3-metadata) crate simply reads that full field as-is, which will include the null padding bytes.

You can remove these padding bytes by using [`.trim_end_matches()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim_end_matches) and `.to_owned()`:

```
artiste = tag.artist.trim_end_matches('\0').to_owned();
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bfd759c1be57e56935e816be228a1da).